# How to generate QR code that stores multiple values

Tags: java, android, odoo-mobile

I wanted to generate a QR code that contains JSON data, I found [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/yp1pmpjo4z?file=/index.js) as an example. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672520/how-make-qr-code-from-object-of-a-class-or-several-data) suggested to use Gson but my project uses Odoo mobile framework and it has an existing Gson in the [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVktd.png) and tried to implement it but it would cause an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336930/gson-implementation-in-gradle-not-working). Is there another way to store multiple values in QR code?

Comment: _"but it would cause an error"_ We have no idea why since you haven't shown us your code or told us what the error is.

Comment: I forgot to include, I updated above

Comment: whats happens if you try to use the existing GSon? I mean not importing a new version of GSon?

Comment: it returns json{}

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun generateQRCode(name: String, phone: String, email: 
String){
    val concatenatedValues = "$name\n$phone\n$email"
    val barcodeEncoder = BarcodeEncoder()
    val hints = mapOf(Pair(EncodeHintType.MARGIN, 0))
    val barCodeImage = 
barcodeEncoder.encodeBitmap(concatenatedValues,BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 400, 
400,hints)
binding.imgBarCode.setImageBitmap(barCodeImage)
}


private fun setUpQrCode(){
    val name = "Name = Husnain Ali Rafique"
    val phone = "Phone = 00000000000"
    val email = "Email = husnainalirafique125@gmail.com"
    generateQRCode(name,phone,email)
}
```

this way by concatinating one can achieve this